# c++ defining templated Base class in derived does not work in IAR ARM compiler

Tags: c++, templates, arm, abstract, iar

This scenario works in Visual studio but not for IAR when building for an ARM device, I get a hard fault.  Here is the scenario

```
enum  BlaEnum
{
  Bla1,
  Bla2
};

template <class T, BlaEnum bla = Bla1>
class A
{
public:
   virtual void Foo() = 0;
   T att;
   BlaEnum bll;
};

class B : public A<int, BlaEnum::Bla2>
{
public:
   void Foo() override;
};

int youu = 9;
void B::Foo() {
++youu;
}

int main(void)
{

 B b;
 A<int>* Base = (A<int>*) &b;  
 Base1->Foo(); //works for win32 but hard faults when it runs in ARM device

 B b2;
 A<int,BlaEnum::Bla2>* Base2 =  &b2;  
 Base2->Foo(); //works for both ARM and win32

}
```

I am defining the Abstract base class templates in the derived class. each derived class will define the enum constant differently and I understand this creates a problem in how dynamic polymorphism is implemented for the IAR compiler.
I have noticed that the vtable fails to be created in the ARM device as vptr points to a inaccessible location. but for win32 the vtable is built just fine for both cases.

The question is, why exactly is this causing a problem for the build to the ARM device but works just fine in win32.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior.  The base class type of `B` is `A<int, BlaEnum::Bla2>` but you declare `Base` as a `A<int>*` which expands to a `A<int, BlaEnum::Bla1>*`.  It is a strict aliasing violation to cast a `A<int, BlaEnum::Bla2>*` to a `A<int, BlaEnum::Bla1>*` and access through it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it had to do with that but what I don't understand still is why this would work when running this on win32 but not on ARM device. how did the VS compiler handle this so that it would still run but the IAR one fail to do so?

Comment: @HadiJaber Undefined Behavior.  Means it could "work" or it could not work.